# Are windows user password easier to crack than linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, password-protection

If i set the same password in both linux and Windows, is it easier for a hacker to break the windows password? If so why and how can i create a windows password in the same security level as Linux?

Comment: Ask this in security.stackexchange.com

Comment: you are right. I asked the question in security.stackexchange.com. Do i have to delete it from here?

Answer (score 2):

There are two big reasons that Windows passwords are easier to crack. When passwords are stored in the computer they are hashed. Hashing a password adds some obscurity to the password. Windows uses MD4 to hash its passwords (without a salt) where as Linux uses 5000 rounds SHA-512 with a salt (last I checked). Essentially Linux uses a hash that has more possible outputs and added obscurity. If you don't know what hashing and salting is I'd suggest you look [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/how-does-hashing-work).

As far as I know you cannot change this in Windows. With Linux.... well with Linux you could change it to store your password as cat no matter what.

A very simplistic example of what hashes look like is:

Lets say your password is 12345

Using MD4 windows would store the password as 23580e2a459f7ea40f9efa148b63cafb

With linux it would add a salt and store it as something that look like this (note this is the hash for 12345 done once without a salt)

3627909a29c31381a071ec27f7c9ca97726182aed29a7ddd2e54353322cfb30a
bb9e3a6df2ac2c20fe23436311d678564d0c8d305930575f60e2d3d048184d79

Comment: Seriously? Windows doesn't salt its hashes?

Comment: This answer would be acceptable if there was less personal opinion in it.

Comment: @Ramhound What personal opinion did add to my answer?

Comment: @Griffin - I suppose its actually your comment I took offense to.  You also fail to mention that how Windows attempts to protect said password beyond simply hashing the password.  It does not matter Windows does not hash the user password, because no user level process, can access the location the hash is even located in.

Comment: @Ramhound The thing is I can grab a flash drive, boot to Linux, and have a program grab and break that hash really really quickly. Windows is attempting to protect the hash from the user. In this case it was my understanding he is trying to protect the hash from the world and in terms of doing that Windows doesn't stack up. Sorry my comment hurt your feelings though

Comment: @Griffin i have posted the question to [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67549/are-windows-users-passwords-easier-to-crack-than-linux) . Can you post your answer there?

Comment: @user3009752 Those guys give far better answers than I do. Whatever they say should trump me. On top of that if they say they need more info I'd give them more.

Comment: @griffen you don't think I can do exactly the something on Linux? With physical access I can just replace the salted hash password with something else I know, unless, the sale is unique even then I only need to know the salt that was used

Comment: @Ramhound That would be great and all (not sure if that works out how you want since I haven't really seen it done) but if you change these things then the user will know. Again here we are talking about a single user vs a larger network. Salting only really becomes important when you don't want someone to know the password of multiple users without them having to try everything again. If you read the link I gave in my answer you'll see that. With Windows it takes less time to crack, when I crack it the crack can be applied to multiple users and users wouldn't know anything has changed.

Comment: @Griffin - Except their password doesn't work?

Comment: @Ramhound However running a more secure hash the added number of possibilities makes it harder to use rainbow tables and the repetition (and salting if multiple users) makes it harder to play guess and check.

Comment: @Ramhound You said you'd just replace the hash with a hash you the plain text to. That would work but when the user tries to log in their plain text wouldn't hash to it and they would be denied. If you instead break the hash and turn it back into plain text you can access the account without alerting the user.